# How many ways can a student answer an 8 question true/false exam if he marks no two consecutive answers the same?

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution

The way I am reading this question is that I have the 8 questions and the following answer can't be the same i.e. 
T/F/T/F/T/F/T/F or F/T/F/T/F/T/F/T so in that case would the answer here not be 2 ways?

Answer (score 2):

It must be only two distinct ways. Start true or start false, later answers in sequence are now determined.